# Como ler um arquivo JSON com vários objetos JSON dentro dele usando nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu preciso ler um `arquivo.json` usando nodejs.
Este arquivo possui vários objetos json dentro de si.

ex:

```
{"foo": "bar"}
{"foo2": "bar2"}
```

Ao usar a seguinte função:

```
const fs = require('fs');

router.get('/logs/file/alerts', (req, res) => {
fs.readFile('/foo/bar/arquivo.json', 'utf-8', (err, snapshot) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    const data = JSON.parse(snapshot);

    res.json(data);
  });
});
```

eu obtive o erro:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 4145

o que me parece ser um erro ao chegar no final do primeiro objeto JSON.

Comment: Cada objeto JSON está em uma linha diferente? Se sim, vc pode fazer um split e fazer o parse de cada linha, assim: `snapshot.split('\n').map(JSON.parse)`. Mas o ideal mesmo seria vc ajustar seu arquivo.json, pois ele não é um JSON válido. Para ser válido, ele deveria ser um array, assim: `[{ "foo": "bar" }, { "foo2": "bar2" }]`.

Comment: obrigado @wldomiciano funcionou perfeitamente usando a sua solução.

Answer (score 1):

A solução foi ler linha por linha do arquivo e ir fazendo um `parse` para cada.
No caso do meu exemplo, também fiz as verificações necessárias pro meu caso.

```
router.get('/logs/file/alerts', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('/foo/bar/logs/alerts/alerts.json', (err, snapshot) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    const results = [];
    const data = snapshot.toString().split('\n');

    for (var k = 0, i = data.length - 1; k < 10; i--) {
      if (data[i].includes('key')) {
        try {
          let jsonResult = JSON.parse(data[i]);
 
          results.push(jsonResult);
          k++;

        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      }
    }

    res.json(results);
  });
});
```